# Google maps problem - not start

Tags: android

Sorry if question is stupid but I am new to android, I need to put map in my android app. I looked at net and I run keytool.exe and get key, but when I run app it crushed and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 android:apiKey="0WR3Cl0evv0U6G2xH9ZnvEFYbDiSDUu_GRovTUQ"
                 />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I don't know what is wrong. I put in manifest in application tag , like I saw on net. Is that all I need to do or I make something wrong ? Did I escape some step ?

Comment: What does logcat say?  Stacktrace?

Answer (score 3):

1. In the manifest file, you might have forgotten to put the "internet" permission.
2. You have to use library in manifest file.
3. You have to Google API add-ons.
4. You have to be very precise while choosing the build target type (android version).

Answer (score 0):

```
 <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Put all these permission in your manifest file

and in  tag put these lines as a child

```
 <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="AIzaSyCzlSw2fSYPx--CgFpk0LBp8Ofm23glhCs"/>
     <meta-data 
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" 
    />
```